# how to set navigation bar transparent to background image in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

i have a project which i use the layer component to display the navbar component and the main
and i use it as a layout for app routes.
the problem is how to display the transparent nav to every route whose have a different main background-image. ?

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <Layer>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/home" exact>
          <Main />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/about">
          <About />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/projects">
          <Projects />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/contact">
          <Contact />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <Redirect to="/home" />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*">
          <NotFoundPage />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Layer>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
const Layer = (props) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Navbar />
      <div className='main'>{props.children}</div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: What is your `Navbar` component look like?

Comment: should i display the code of Navbar component in the post ?

Comment: Sure, it's best if you can have them in a codesanbox.

Comment: ok, gonna add them the component and the css module if you want it too.

Comment: Yeah, that will help a lot